# How do I apply custom styles to a SweetAlert2 popup?

Tags: css, vue.js, sweetalert2

I am using the SweetAlert2 Library in a Vue.js project. The library is working fine with all its features except custom styling.

Based on the documentation, to customize a popup you should add a `customClass` field to the options object where you define custom class names for each component of the popup.

That is exactly what I did. but the styles do not change.

The code used to include the library:
`import Swal from 'sweetalert2'`

The code used to fire a swal popup:

```
Swal.fire({
    confirmButtonText: this.confirmBtnTxt,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    showCancelButton: false,
    title: `Hello ${this.user.firstName} ${this.user.lastName}`,
    text: 'Can you please confirm your company',
    input: 'select',
    customClass: {
        container: 'pp-container',
        popup: 'pp',
        header: 'pp-header',
        title: 'pp-title',
        content: 'pp-content',
        htmlContainer:'pp-html-container',
        input: 'pp-input'
    },
```

I have provided all the necessary custom class names, and I am giving those classes styling rules in the styles section of the component:

```
// Customising swal alerts 
.pp {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px -10px #4a4a4a;
    background:black;
}
.pp-title {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.pp-input {
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    background: #f0f2f7;
    padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}
.pp-html-container {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #9a9a9a;
}
```

But the styling doesn't change (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot of popup]

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, Have you tried using `::v-deep`?

Comment: What's that ? a Vue.js directive or what ?

Comment: It helps you to apply styles on child components. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-vue-deep-css-selector

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it is working for me.
Check the demo.

```js
const showAlert = () => {
  Swal.fire("Update Successful", "Changes updated successfully!", "success");
}
```

```css
.swal2-popup {
  background: #222 !important;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  color: whitesmoke !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.6.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<button onclick="showAlert()">Show Alert</button>
```